# Is there a Box2d b2World::ShiftOrigin function in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Is there an equivalent Box2d b2World::ShiftOrigin function in Libgdx? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [libgdx's Box2D introduction](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d), "The Box2D implementation in libgdx is a thin Java wrapper about the C++ engine", which would be in [`World.java` in the libgdx sources](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.java), but it's not.

So: **No**, there isn't.

…yet!

You could ask nicely in the [libgdx issue tracker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues). (Or maybe implement it yourself and send a pull request if you know C++ Box2D? I'm surprised how straightforward their wrapper code looks.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kind of figured this was the case but thought that maybe I was missing something because it's such a simple function to have. I will try to implement it myself then.